# Installing app on new phone

Tags: bitcoin-wallet-app

I may have to get a new phone very soon.  When I install Copay on the new phone how do I log in to access my account?  Currently on the phone I have it is permanently logged in.  I see no option to log out.  So again, when I install the app on a new phone how will I get into my account because I have no recorded log info.

Answer (score 1):

You should get out your recovery phrase and install copay on the new phone when they ask you for recovery phrase (usually 12 words) add it and your wallet should work as the old phone.